# Updating the Jlabel text by a loop in java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I want to update the Jlabel text in every second as long as the loop is running. how could I do this? I want to do as this fromat.

```
JPanel jpnl=new JPanel();
    jfrm.add(jpnl);
    String[] fonts=GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
    jlab = new JLabel("This is Label");
    jpnl.add(jlab);

        for(int i=0;i<fonts.length;i++){
            System.out.println(fonts[i]);
            jlab.setText(fonts[i]);
            jlab.setFont(new Font(fonts[i],Font.PLAIN,30));
            jlab.setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        }
```

Comment: If just time is an issue and you have no other requirements specified, you can just use Thread.sleep(1000) inside the loop

Comment: Can you explain more simple Thread.sleep(1000) within the loop will not work.

Comment: First off, don't use `Thread.sleep`, it will simply make the loop take longer to run and block the UI from been updated.  The conical answer is to use a Swing `Timer`

Comment: @MadProgrammer  plz explain How I use timer here because same issue I am facing with Thread.sleep().

Comment: @RavibhushanKumar I'm kind of left wondering if you even tried to google "java swing timer" before replying, it would have lead you onto a wealth of information, so is also litter with countless examples

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Swing's single threaded nature precludes using a loop or `Thread.sleep` in the way you seem to be trying.  Doing so, will simply block the UI and prevent it from been painted/updated until the loop is completed.

Because Swing is not thread safe, you can't simply use another `Thread` and the above approaches to update the UI, without jumping through some hoops

The conical answer to your question is to use a Swing `Timer`, which triggers an update at a regular bases. Because these updates are triggered within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, it makes it safe to use when you want to update the UI.

Take a closer look at [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private String[] fonts;
        private final JLabel jlab;
        private int index = 0;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            fonts = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
            jlab = new JLabel("This is Label");
            add(jlab);

            Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    updateFont();
                    index++;
                    if (index >= fonts.length) {
                        ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                    }
                }
            });
            timer.setInitialDelay(0);
            timer.start();
        }

        protected void updateFont() {
            System.out.println(fonts[index]);
            jlab.setText(fonts[index]);
            jlab.setFont(new Font(fonts[index], Font.PLAIN, 30));
            jlab.setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);           
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```